# getting an id of the button when button in mulitple arrays is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

As I am doing an stockmanagement application system in php..As I have many buttons related to the product..I want to get the button id and want to make changes in database...I am not getting my button id.Please help me..

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id=100 onclick="rowAdding(0)">Pizza - $20</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id=101 onclick="rowAdding(1)">Burger - $30</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id=102 onclick="rowAdding(2)">Springroll - $25</button>`
```

here i am trying to get my buttonid and do some scripts

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['button'])){
    echo"Authenticating";
    $buttonnumber  = array_pop(array_keys($_REQUEST['button']));
    $buttonvalue  = array_pop($_REQUEST['button']);
}else{
    echo "Not Updated into database";
}
```

here function rowAdding() script...

```
function rowAdding(index,qty){
    if(typeof qty == 'undefined')
        qty=1;

    if(products[index][2]<=0){
        products[index][2]=1;

        products[index][3]=(products[index][1] * products[index][2]);

        var row = $("<tr id='product"+index+"'>");
        row.append($("<td>"+products[index][0]+"</td>"))
            .append($("<td>$"+products[index][1]+"</td>"))
            .append($("<td><button onclick='rowAdding("+index+",-1)'>-</button> <span id='product_qty"+index+"'>"+products[index][2]+"</span> <button onclick='rowAdding("+index+",1)'>+</button></td>"))
            .append($("<td id='product_amount"+index+"'>$"+products[index][3]+"</td>"))
        $("#myTable tbody").append(row);

    }else{
        products[index][2]+=qty;
        if(products[index][2]<=0){
            products[index][2]=0;
            products[index][3]=0;
            $("#product"+index).remove();
        }else{
            products[index][3]=(products[index][1] * products[index][2]);
            $("#product_qty"+index).html(products[index][2]);
            $("#product_amount"+index).html("$"+products[index][3]);
        }
    }

    var totalAmount=0;
    for(var i=0;i<products.length;i++){
        totalAmount+=products[i][3];
    }

    $("#total_amount").html("$"+totalAmount);

}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you are trying to get your button id

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Those elements alone tell us very little. What does `rowAdding()` do?

Comment: here i am including those  code sir...

Comment: Well for a start your function has 2 parameters and your call has only one. Therefore the javascript is probably not even compiling

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i recall javascript allows you to call a function without having to specify all the parameters. it's just that those you don't specify will have undefined errors when you try and use them and thus the if statement (because in javascript there really are no easy way to do optional paramters)

Comment: And `<button>`'s do not cause a submit so the PHP code will not run unless the `<button type="submit"...>` is used

Comment: And then as they have no `name="something`` attribute they will not be passed to the PHP script anyway.

Comment: @Memor-X Hmm I think you may be right. Sort of fits with the first line of OP's code anyway

Comment: thanks sir..it helps me a lot....@RiggsFolly and  @Memor-X